# Ubuntu 18.04 not using Nvidia card

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-geforce

I know there exist many questions and answers on the same topic all over the internet, still I couldn't fix the issue on my laptop.

Below are the configurations of my laptop.

- i5 8th Gen with integrated graphics
- Nvidia **MX250**
- Ubuntu 18.04 (dual booted with Windows 10)

I have installed the recommended driver for the nvidia card - **nvidia-driver-435**.

Below are some observations:

- Intel graphic card is displayed in the *About* section in *Settings*.
- NVIDIA X Server settings is not listing the nvidia GPU, but PRIME profiles are available and nvidia is already selected as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck6WB.png).
- `lshw -c display` shows nvidia card along with the Intel card.

```
*-display
    description: 3D controller
    product: NVIDIA Corporation
    vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    version: a1
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: bus_master cap_list
    configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
    resources: irq:150 memory:93000000-93ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

- `nvidia-smi` gives below output, seems like the nvidia GPU is not in use.

```
Wed Sep 11 17:57:57 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX250       Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   40C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- `nvidia-detector` outputs `none`

Interestingly, if I run `nvidia-smi` from a **TTY** session, **can see some processes which use the GPU**.

```
Wed Sep 11 17:54:42 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX250       Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   38C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     12MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2564      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             7MiB |
|    0      2716      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                           4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

More observations:

- If I select **Gnome on Xorg** or **Ubuntu** from the login screen, I get a stuck screen and nothing will be working (I usually switch to TTY session and do a restart when this occurs). But **Gnome** and **Ubuntu on Wayland** has no   problem after login.

Any help is much appreciated.
Cheers!

---

**Edit**: I got my GPU working. I have posted an answer below.

Comment: When I go to NVIDIA's drivers site, the MX250 is supposed to be using https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/149138 Version 430.40 , What is the URL where you found the reference to nvidia-driver-435 ?

Comment: @K7AAY `ubuntu-drivers devices` command showed the driver along with the nvidia graphic card. I installed the recommended driver.

Answer (score 1):

Finally Ubuntu on my laptop is using the NVIDIA card!! **I reinstalled Ubuntu**. I did not connect my laptop to the internet while I installed Ubuntu last time. So the OS might not have identified the devices and corresponding drivers correctly (I am not sure about this though). This time I connected to the WiFi before installing. After the installation only one proprietary driver was listed in the *Additional Driver* tab in *Software and Updates*, while last time there were two. I selected that driver and rebooted after its installation.

After reboot I had below observations:

- NVIDIA graphic card is displayed in the *About* section in *Settings*.
- NVIDIA GPU is listed in NVIDIA X Server settings.

Interestingly when I switched to the GNOME session from the login screen, NVIDIA GPU was not getting used by the system. So I switched to GNOME on Xorg and the system started using NVIDIA GPU.

`nvidia-smi` gives below output now:

```
Mon Sep 23 18:10:15 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.26       Driver Version: 430.26       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX250       Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   45C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    305MiB /  2002MiB |     12%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      3120      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           160MiB |
|    0      3262      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         120MiB |
|    0      5052      G   /usr/bin/vlc                                  22MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your specific case where some small thing does seem to run on the GPU. However, with problems like these, I found that installing Bumblebee and Primus can help:

`sudo apt-get install bumblebee primus`

Then, you should be able to run programs with your GPU using `optirun program_name` or `primusrun program_name`.

This thread was very helpful for issues I had getting optirun to work: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bumblebee/+bug/1758243 Particularly answer 31:

> 1. The first change needed is to edit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf as follows:
>
> LibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
>   XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-418/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input
>   XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
>
> This was expected because the path is different for every NVIDIA driver.
>
> 2. The second change needed was to export this:
>
> export __GLVND_DISALLOW_PATCHING=1
>
> And with these two changes everything works.

In your case 418 should presumably be replaced by 435.

Comment: I tried this, but was getting this error `[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)`. I tried with `sudo`, still got same error.